# Inserting date variable into char variable in SQL

Tags: sas, proc-sql

The bday and date variables in the work.record file are stored as date9. while the date and birth_day variables are datetime but appear to be char values; the informat and format for the orion.test variables is $10.

How do I convert my variables so that they can be inserted into the ones in orion.test?

```
proc sql;
    insert into orion.test  (date, birth_day)
        select r.date r.bday FROM work.record AS r;
quit;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `put` to convert to character.

```
proc sql;
    insert into orion.test  (date, birth_day)
        select put(r.date,mmddyy10.), put(r.bday,mmddyy10.) FROM work.record AS r;
quit;
```

Just check that the format is appropriate (whatever format your char values in `orion.test` are).

Comment: I changed my code to include put, but now the log is coming up with this error
"CLI execute error: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string."

Comment: You likely have some values that can't convert properly.